# how to keep specific attributes of views in custom listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

How can I change attributes of views inside holder based on position ?
this problem only arises when using recycles 
with a data holder class. I can set different title for each different textview based on position, but I am not able to change textsize of each these textviews based on position.

of course with recycleView = false it works just fine because views will not be recycled but how to make it work with recycler on ?

```
boolean recycleView = false;
ArrayList<SocialItem> list;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null || !recycleView) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.social_list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.si_title1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.title1.setText(list.get(position).getTitle1());

    //changes textsize of textview to fit in specific width, and saves in our holder list, and sets from it in textview
    list.get(position).setTxtSize1(Util.correctTVWidth(holder.title1, 110));
    holder.title1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, list.get(position).getTxtSize1());

    return convertView;
}
```

the solution of **Kingfisher Phuoc** works but why the following code won't work ?
what I think it does is, it saves calculated textsize in a simple pojo holder based on position and I set textsize from it in view, shouldn't it work ?.

```
    //changes textsize of textview to fit in specific width, and saves in our holder list, and sets from it in textview
    list.get(position).setTxtSize1(Util.correctTVWidth(holder.title1, 110));
    holder.title1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, list.get(position).getTxtSize1());
```

Comment: what your function `Util.correctTVWidth(holder.title1, 110)` do?

Comment: returns adjusted textsize to fit in textview if the text is long

Answer (score 1):

If I dont misunderstand, you need change view in a specific position, right? If it's what you want, you can do it. Why not? Look at example below:

```
if(position == somePositionYouWant){ // change textsize at specific position
    holder.yourTextView.setTextSize(yourtextSize);
}else{
    // you must reset your textsize in other position or everything will be mess
    holder.yourTextView.setTextSize(defaultTextSize);
}
```

If I'm correct, you use `Util.correctTVWidth(holder.title1, 110)` to calculate `textsize`. however, you should remember that `convertView` is reused. That means if any row is invisible, it will be reused for next visible view. Example, 10 item in listview is visible, when you scroll down, 11 (12)th item will be visible and reuse view of 1st item, and `TextView` attributes are keep from 1st item. If you calculate textsize based on `holder.title1` of 1st item for 11th item, maybe it's the reason your code not work.